# On ICS devices Current Activity disappearing when screen gets locked

Tags: android, android-manifest

In activity manifest file i have marked it as android:noHistory="true" because I did not want the screen to be added to the activity stack.
when I lock the screen and unlock it. The activity disappears and the previous screen appears. This should not happen. Please any one can suggest me, how can i handle this on ICS devices. However its working fine on Gingerbread devices.

Answer (score 0):

Remove android:noHistory="true" in android manifest file and call the finish when you move out of that Activity. This will remove the activity completely from the stack and it will not be displayed in your backstack. I hope this will work for you